# Go program memory consumption keeps increasing on Windows Server 2016

Tags: go, memory-management, memory-leaks

This is my Go code. I am using version 1.13
Once the code starts running, the memory consumption continuously increases, never decreasing. I dont think I am creating new variables. I am only reusing global variables for all the storage.

I read online that the GC in Go should kick in every 2 minutes...?

**EDIT:** I am monitoring the memory consumption of the program on the Windows Task Manager. And the Memory starts at ~5MB, when the program starts to run and increases 0.3~0.5 MB every minute.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"
    "runtime/debug"
    "strings"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
)

var path = os.Args[1]
var table = os.Args[4]
var backupPath = os.Args[2]
var location = os.Args[5]

var server = "localhost"
var port = 1433
var user = "###"
var password = "###"
var database = os.Args[3]
var ctx = context.Background()

var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO [" + database + "].[dbo].[" + table + "] ([meter_id],[time_stamp],[r_voltage],[y_voltage],[b_voltage],[ry_voltage],[yb_voltage],[br_voltage],[r_current],[y_current],[b_current],[kva],[kw],[kvar],[power_factor],[freq],[kwh],[run_hr],[updated_date]) VALUES"
var updateStatusQuery = "UPDATE EMS_Location_Status SET active='100',mailed='N',Updated_Date=getdate(),Error_desc='Data is coming from FTPS' where Location_Id ='" + location + "'"
var db *sql.DB

var connString = fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;user id=%s;password=%s;port=%d;database=%s;",
    server, user, password, port, database)

var err error
var files []string
var tempInsertQuery string
var csvFile *os.File
var csvLines [][]string
var i int
var line []string
var point string
var processedFile []string
var fileName string
var iterFile string
var c = 10

func processFile(file string, table string) {
    fmt.Println("Processing file...", file)
    tempInsertQuery = insertQuery + " "
    csvFile, err = os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        for err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Encountered error in opening file.. trying again in 10 seconds.")
            time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
            csvFile, err = os.Open(file)
        }
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    csvLines, err = csv.NewReader(csvFile).ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    for i, line = range csvLines {
        if i == 0 {
            continue
        } else {
            tempInsertQuery = tempInsertQuery + "("

            for _, point = range line {
                tempInsertQuery = tempInsertQuery + "'" + point + "'" + ","
            }
            tempInsertQuery = tempInsertQuery[0:len(tempInsertQuery)-1] + ", GETDATE()" + "), "
        }
    }
    tempInsertQuery = tempInsertQuery[0 : len(tempInsertQuery)-2]
    // Execute query
    //fmt.Println(tempInsertQuery)
    _, err = db.QueryContext(ctx, tempInsertQuery)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    _, err = db.QueryContext(ctx, updateStatusQuery)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    csvFile.Close()
    fmt.Println("Done processing file ", file)
    backupFile(file)
    runtime.GC()
    debug.FreeOSMemory()
}

func backupFile(file string) {
    fmt.Println("Backing up...", file)
    processedFile = strings.Split(file, "\\")
    fileName = processedFile[len(processedFile)-1]
    err = os.Rename(file, backupPath+fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func scanner(scanPath string, table string) {

    err = filepath.Walk(scanPath, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if strings.Contains(path, ".csv") {
            files = append(files, path)
        }
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, iterFile = range files {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        processFile(iterFile, table)
    }

    files = files[:0]
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(connString)
    // Create connection pool
    db, err = sql.Open("sqlserver", connString)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating connection pool: ", err.Error())
    }
    err = db.PingContext(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Connected to server!\n")
    fmt.Printf("Initiating...\n")

    for c > 0 {
        scanner(path, table)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }

    fmt.Println("Quitting..")
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: "I read online that the GC in Go should kick in every 2 minutes...?" -- This is not true. The GC kicks in when it needs to, and is based on memory consumption, not time. But that's probably not really related to your question.

Comment: To address the core of your question: There's not nearly enough information here to help answer. First, why do you believe memory consumption continues to increase? And to what extent? How much memory is it actually using, and over what time frame?

Comment: `db.QueryContext()` returns an `sql.Rows` which has a `Close()` method. Do call that. Preferably call all `Close()` methods using `defer` so they get called even in case of panics.

Comment: I am monitoring the memory consumption of the program on the Windows Task Manager. And the Memory starts at ~5MB, when the program starts to run and increases 0.3~0.5 MB every minute.

Comment: Did you monitor the memory over several days? If not: No leak. It is basically impossible to detect a leak with the Task Manager if only observing it a few hours.

Comment: I think you are making an assumption on the behavior of `debug.FreeOSMemory()` which is implementation dependent. With some versions of Linux the memory is made available to the OS but it will not reclaim it unless it needs it. As others have said, what happens if you leave it running - does the OS eventually run out of memory?

Comment: @icza calling the `Close()` method on `db.QueryContext()` reduced the rate at which memory usage increases. Now it is growing much slowly. Thanks a ton! I have closed the file pointers after every iteration. Anything I am missing..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General concept in Go is whatever implements [`io.Closer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Closer) (that has a `Close()` method), when you have such a value which you don't intend to use anymore, you should call its `Close()` method which in general frees resources which otherwise may not be freed immediately or not at all (ever).

Your `db.QueryContext()` call is [`sql.Conn.QueryContext()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Conn.QueryContext) which returns an [`*sql.Rows`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows) value which has a `Close()` method. Do call that. Currently you're not even storing the returned `sql.Rows`.

Do it like this:

```
var rows *sql.Rows
rows, err = db.QueryContext(ctx, tempInsertQuery)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
if err2 := rows.Close(); err2 != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error closing rows:", err2
}
```

Apply this at all uses of `Conn.QueryContext()`.

Whenever makes sense, use `defer` to call such `Close()` methods, so it will be executed even if your code panics or have a `return` statement before calling that "manually".

Such example in your code is `csvFile.Close()`. There are `return`s before that, and if one of those branch is executed, the `csvFile` will not be closed.

Do it like this:

```
csvFile, err = os.Open(file)
if err != nil {
    for err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Encountered error in opening file.. trying again in 10 seconds.")
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
        csvFile, err = os.Open(file)
    }
    fmt.Println(err)
}
defer func() {
    if err2 := csvFile.Close(); err2 != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error closing csvFile:", err2
    }
}()
```